# Getting increase in memory after merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, merge

i need some help to understand pandas mechanism and python memory.
i have a dataframe (with around 1500000 rows) and i merge it with another dataframe.
before the merge my process memory used is 3GB and after it's 4.75GB.
how after merging and getting a df with less rows my memory increase??

```
def __filter_data(self, data, list_of_permutations, cols_for_id):
    perm_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_permutations, columns=cols_for_id)
    flag = False
    geo = []
    if 'ref_country_id' in data.columns:
        geo = [col for col in perm_df.columns if '_geo_' in col]
        if len(geo) > 1:
            raise Exception('***multiple geo columns')
        if len(geo)==1:
            data.rename(columns={'ref_country_id': geo[0]}, inplace=True)
            flag = True
    try:
        log.warning(
            f'BEFORE merge data  , memory used: {psutil.virtual_memory().used / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)} GB, available:'
            f' {psutil.virtual_memory().available / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)} GB,'
            f' free: {psutil.virtual_memory().free / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)} GB')

        data = data.merge(perm_df, on=cols_for_id)

        log.warning(
            f'AFTER merge data  , memory used: {psutil.virtual_memory().used / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)} GB, available:'
            f' {psutil.virtual_memory().available / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)} GB,'
            f' free: {psutil.virtual_memory().free / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)} GB')
```

Comment: possible reasons are: source dataframes didn't go out of scope and cannot be GC-ed; or, they just were'nt GC-ed *yet*  (upd: looking at the code, it seems to be the latter)

Comment: isn't merging two dataframes just creating a new one? thus increasing memory usage